# is there any way to save the value of onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm having a question about onChange, so I was trying to pick up and send a value from my onChange to (''http://localhost:3000/search''), but when I press the (Enter) key it enters the page but ends up deleting the values of my onChange coming back undefined, is there any way to save my onChange and send to another page? without retone me undefined

My code:

```js
function handleKeyPress(event: any) {
        if(event.keyCode === 13){
          open('http://localhost:3000/search')
        }
      }

    function search(e: any) {
    
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/search", {params: {q: e.target.value}})
    
    }
    
    return(
        <>
            <div className={styles.Header}>

                <input name='q' type="text" placeholder='Buscar' onChange={(e)=>search(e)} onKeyDown={(e)=>handleKeyPress(e)}/>

                <div></div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

Comment: Do you want to send `{params: {q: e.target.value}}` to 'http://localhost:3000/search'?

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `window.open`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67616734/10104154) should help.

Otherwise, I would suggest you using react-router's [useNaviage](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate). You can pass your search param in search property, and access the param on the target page using [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams).

```
import { useNavigate, createSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

...

const navigage  = useNavigate()
function handleKeyPress(event: any) {
  if(event.keyCode === 13){
    navigage(
      `${"/search"}?${createSearchParams({q: e.target.value})}`
    );
  }
}

...
```

in "/search" page

```
 let { q } = useParams();
```

[Here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/installation) how to setup react-router for your project

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout becouse the search function maybe not is loaded yet

> setTimeout(open('http://localhost:3000/search'), 500)